# Chance of death in a 5 year period if I know my chance of death every year

Tags: probability

I was wondering how to calculate the following:
I know the average chance of death per year for a certain age.
What is the average chance of death for a 5 year period then?

Is it simply additive?
The chances are listed here (jaar is the dutch word for Year)

[Chance Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09wt9.png)

Comment: It cannot be simply additive for then you would be guaranteed to die twice if you lived long enough! Or, less strikingly, probability of death within a time span would exceed 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your chance of survival multiplies.

If your chance of death in three years is one percent, two percent and 
three percent, then your chance of survival is $0.99*0.98*0.97$

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an excerpt of a life table, which is used in the actuarial sciences.  The entries you have are ages $x$, and the corresponding probabilities $q_x$ of death within one year for a life aged $x$.

To obtain the the probability of death within $5$ years, denoted ${}_5 q_x$, you would observe that it is the complementary probability, survival for at least $5$ years, called ${}_5 p_x$, that can be expressed as a product of the individual annual survival probabilities; that is to say,

$${}_5 p_x = (p_x)(p_{x+1})(p_{x+2})(p_{x+3})(p_{x+4}).$$  Since $q_x + p_x = 1$ for any age $x$, we can then write $${}_5 q_x = 1 - {}_5 p_x = 1 - (1 - q_x)(1 - q_{x+1})(1 - q_{x+2})(1 - q_{x+3})(1 - q_{x+4}).$$  In your table, for someone aged $59.5$, the $5$-year failure (death) probability is $${}_5 q_{59.5} = 1 - (1 - 0.005380)(1 - 0.005980)(1 - 0.006320)(1 - 0.006800)(1 - 0.007120) = 0.031204.$$  However, for a life aged $60.5$, $${}_5 q_{60.5} = 0.0335904.$$  A more complete table would allow you to make projections for survival beyond age $64.5$.